# Redirect user to Phone Settings windows phone 8 application

Tags: redirect, windows-phone-8, popup, settings, messagebox

I am trying to make a timer app and I need to prevent the screen from timing out. Since Windows Phone does not allow me to control that, I want to display a pop up to the user, giving him/her the option to be redirected to the phone's Settings page so that he/she can manually set the screen timeout.

Comment: Can you provide us the code that you have so that we can help you find the error?

Answer (score 1):

All of the available URI schemes for the Settings page are listed here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937(v=vs.105).aspx

The URI scheme you're looking for is...

```cs
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-lock:"));
```

**3rd party apps**

Lots of 3rd party app have URI schemes as well, there's a handy list on the [Nokia Developer Wiki](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Wiki_Home):

http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/URI_Association_Schemes_List